# I can send smtp message on a localHost But i cant send it on a Live WebSite

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, smtp, umbraco

[image]im using Asp.net And I have the Umbraco Cms on my project 
i implemented The Send message using razor syntax

im submitting a from to the following  razor syntax

```
@{ if (IsPost)
{
    string name = Request["name"];
    string email = Request["email"];
    string phone = Request["phone"];
    string city = Request["city"];
    string note = Request["note"];
    NetworkCredential basicCredential =new NetworkCredential("*****@gmail.com", "******");
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    //var from = new MailAddress(Email.Text);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
    mail.To.Add("tupacmuhammad5@gmail.com");
    mail.Subject = "Torcan WebSite Contact Us";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
    mail.Body = "You just got a contact email:\n" +
                "Name: " + name + "\n"
                + "Email: " + email + "\n"
                 + "TelePhone: " + phone + "\n"
                + "Address: " + city + "\n"
                  + "Message: " + note + "\n";
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    smtp.Credentials = basicCredential;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {


    }
    finally
    {
        smtp.Dispose();
    }


}
```

}

it works perfect on My localHost But on a live server its  thorws a runtime error "after i remove the try catch "

i cant find out what seems to be problem 
im writing this code in umbraco backoffice tamplate i have the server on onther country and i dont have access to it any help ? please ?

Comment: You need to edit & add the runtime error/stack details you observe when you remove or disable the try/catch

Comment: Its Only shows me the the "run time error" im running it on client and editing the page from the umbraco Server

Comment: You need to show us the detailed error message

Comment: i added a screen shot of the error

Comment: If you look at that page it tells you what to do to enable detailed error output, if you do that it will tell you whats going wrong.

Comment: thanks alot i understand 
but i dont have access to the server to enable them unfortunately 
so im just blind shooting on this one

Comment: Perhaps port 587 is not open for outbound connections on that server/network?  Try a different SMTP server?

Comment: Or add code in your catch to output the exception details.

Comment: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 
thats the error

Comment: You're either not sending a username and password to authenticate the SMTP connection (check your SMTP settings in your Web.config), or the information you're sending is incorrect.

Comment: If you have access to the Umbraco back office, install the Config Tree plugin which will allow you to edit the web.config file to change the CustomErrors configuration.

Comment: Can u please Answer so i can close the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was that the Server is located in Germany so when the server tries to open my Gmail account. its a different country and never seen action from there.
so all i had to do is to open my gmail via remote access on the server machine via a browser and confirmed it was me then every thing worked perfectly.